# How to get minimum value from 2D array in c# and the indices of that cell?

Tags: c#, arrays, minimum, type-2-dimension

I want to get the minimum value from 2 dimensional array [1024,9] ,and I want the position of this minimum value.

Hint: the last column is flag "if flag == 0 : check this row, else : skip this row"

I tried this cod ,but it did not help me ...

```
float min = fill_file[0, 0];
            int ind = 0;
            int ind2 = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    if (fill_file[i, j] < min && fill_file[i, 8] == 0)
                    {
                        min = fill_file[i, j];
                        ind2 = i;
                        ind = j;
                    }
                }   
            }
```

---

This is all code based on your request

```
int t = 0;
        while (t < 1024)
        {
            float min = fill_file[0, 0];
            int ind = 0;
            int ind2 = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    if (fill_file[i, j] < min && fill_file[i, 8] == 0)
                    {
                        min = fill_file[i, j];
                        ind2 = i;
                        ind = j;
                    }
                }   
            }

            machens[ind] = machens[ind] + min;
            fill_file[ind2, 8] = 1;

            for (int r = 0; r < 1024; r++)
            {
                if (fill_file[r, 8] != 1)
                    fill_file[r, ind] = fill_file[r, ind] + min;
            }

            t++;
        }//End while
```

Comment: How about a much smaller 2-d array with example data?

Comment: And why it doesn't work? It looks perfectly well to me. What do you want the end result to be: fill_file[ind, ind2] or fill_file[ind2, ind]?

Comment: Note that the resulting minimum will be in `fill_file[ind2, ind]` and **not** in `fill_file[ind, ind2]`.

Comment: What's wrong with this code? What's i8 == 0 trying to do?

Comment: to add min to one dimensional array in index [ind]

Comment: Assuming there's at least one row with the flag set to zero, then the minimum value will be zero, j will be 8, and i will be the last row that has flag == 0. I don't think this is what you want.  -- Sorry didn't see the (j < 8)!!!

Comment: after that add min to all array fill_file[fill_file.Length,ind]

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly:**

If it happens that none of the rows have the "use this row" flag set to zero (with zero meaning "use this row"), you will obviously get a wrong result.
I guess this will never happen for your data?

**Secondly:**

If `fill_file[0,8]` is nonzero, you will still be initialising `min` to `fill_file[0,0]` even though the flag says you shouldn't use that row.
In that case, if `fill_file[0,0]`happens to be less than all the values in any of the rows for which `fill_file[row,8]` is zero then you will get the wrong result.

I would be tempted to initialise `min` to `float.MaxValue` and `ind` and `ind2` to -1 each, so you know if they haven't been updated.
And call them `minRow` and `minCol`.

**Thirdly:**

There's an obvious optimisation: If [row,8] is nonzero, there's no point in running the inner iteration for that row.

Putting this all together:

```
float minValue = float.MaxValue;
int minCol = -1;
int minRow = -1;

for (int row = 0; row < 1024; row++)
{
    if (fill_file[row, 8] == 0)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
        {
            if (fill_file[row, col] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = fill_file[row, col];
                minRow = row;
                minCol = col;
            }
        }
    }
}

// If minRow is < 0, then no valid data exists.
// Otherwise, fill_file[minRow, minCol] contains minVal
```

Answer (score 0):

## This code:

```
var min_ij = Enumerable.Range(0, 1024)
    .Where(i => fillFile[i, 9] == 0)
    .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Range(0, 8)
        .Select(j => new { i, j }))
    .ArgMin(ij => fillFile[ij.i, ij.j]);

int min_i = min_ij.i;
int min_j = min_ij.j;
```

## Using this helper function:

```
public static TElem ArgMin<TElem, TField>(this IEnumerable<TElem> set, Func<TElem, TField> objective, bool allowEmptySet = false)
    where TField : IComparable<TField>
{
    if (!set.Any() && !allowEmptySet)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot perform ArgMin on an empty set.");

    bool first = true;
    TElem bestElem = default(TElem);
    TField bestObjective = default(TField);
    foreach (TElem currElem in set)
    {
        TField currObjective = objective(currElem);
        if (first || currObjective.CompareTo(bestObjective) < 0)
        {
            first = false;
            bestElem = currElem;
            bestObjective = currObjective;
        }
    }

    return bestElem;
}
```

Comment: And the position of that value is...?

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward problem. Try something like this:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
  int[,] values = new int[1024,9];
  Random rng = new Random() ;

  // initialise the array
  for ( int r = 0 ; r < 1024 ; ++r )
  {
    for ( int c = 0 ; c < 9 ; ++c )
    {
      values[r,c] = rng.Next() ;
    }

    int x = rng.Next(10) ;
    if ( x == 1 )
    {
      values[r,8] = 0 ;
    }
  }

  int? minValue = null ;
  int? minRow   = null ;
  int? minCol   = null ;
  for ( int r = 0 ; r < 1024 ; ++r )
  {
    bool skipRow = 0 == values[r,8] ;
    if ( skipRow ) continue ;
    for ( int c = 0 ; c < 8 ; ++c )
    {
      int cell = values[r,c] ;
      if ( !minValue.HasValue || cell < minValue )
      {
        minValue = cell ;
        minRow   = r ;
        minCol   = c ;
      }
    }
  }

  // display the results
  if ( minValue.HasValue )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Minimum: values[{0},{1}] is {2}" , minRow , minCol , minValue );
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "all rows skipped" );
  }
  return ;
}
```